Inconsistent behavior between function and arrow function
I am a beginner in Ts and I have encountered a confusing problem. Please help me solve it, thanks
function f1(x:number):void {
  return x; // error
}

const f2:(s:number) => void = (s) =>{
  return s // ok
} 

way? In my opinion, they should behave consistently, and I have activated strict mode

Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Performance" is probably not a good word for the title, since it implies things like speed, but that's not what you mean.  Maybe change it to something more neutral like "behavior"?

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function
You are not typing the arrow function correctly.
Do it like
const f2 = (s:number): void => {return s}
This could have been solved with a simple google search of
"How to type arrow functions in typescript"

This is true that this is the more appropriate syntax, but by doing some testing, all of these return the same thing, the only difference is that the error isnt caught in f2.

The arrow function in OP's question is not typed incorrectly. The line at the bottom of your answer is unkind, and while frustration when people behave counter to your expectations is understandable, it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow, especially when interacting with new users.
